# QGIS - LS Factor- Field Based

Tags: qgis, saga, rusle

I'm working on the LS analysis for slope using QGIS - LS Factor Field Based Tool. I have input the DEM. However, the LS layers failed to generate, and it shows the errors as the SAGA version 7.8.2 is not supported.

I'm using QGIS version 3.28.8.

Is there any way that I can solve this?

[image]

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.